# Java For Loop of Arrays/Lists

Tags: java, arrays, list, for-loop

I have the following for loops in my java program that iterate through arrays.  I realize now that this is not effective, because I am saving 5 locations per customer and when this loop runs, it prints the entire array of saved locations (by the fifth loop it prints all 5 saved locations).

**I just want to print the last saved location that the customer searched.**

I considered a while loop outside the 1st for loop and then setting the variable false somewhere within the last for loop, but this did not work. The area of concern in my below code is the `c.getLocations()`, which stores all of the locations as the customer searches. Is there any way I can revise this, so it is only giving me the last added location?

```
List<CustomerCityRule> appliedRules = new LinkedList<CustomerCityRule>();

        for (Customer c: WeatherSimulator.customers) {
            //GUI.outputTextArea.append("customer loop: success");
            for (Location l: c.getLocations()) {
                //GUI.outputTextArea.append("\nlocation loop: success");
                for (CustomerCityRule r: WeatherSimulator.rules) {
                    if (r.isApplicable(l) && !appliedRules.contains(r)) {
                        appliedRules.add(r);
                        //GUI.outputTextArea.append("\nrule check: success");
                    }
                }
                    GUI.outputTextArea.append("\n" + c.toString()  + "\n" + l.toString() + "\nTemperature: " + l.getTemp() + "\u00b0" + "F");
                    for(CustomerCityRule r1 : appliedRules){
                        String s = r1.getClass().getSimpleName();
                        GUI.outputTextArea.append("\nNotification: " + s);
                    }
                    GUI.outputTextArea.append("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            }
        }
```

Comment: in pseudo-code, instead of `array.append(s); print(array)`, do `array.append(s); print(s)` so you only print out whatever you appended, instead of the entire array.

Comment: what data structure do you use to store Locations? If you use an Array of size `M`, just get the element of the array at position `M-1`. If I got your problem correctly, that is...

Comment: Why the downvotes to the question people? It may have a simple answer, but there is nothing wrong with that. Welcome to SO gissypooh :)

Comment: Thank you for those trying to help :) Locations are stored as ArrayList<Location>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your problem correctly (correct me if I am wrong), you only want to check the last `Location` stored in `c.getLocations()`, and not all (5) of them.

Assuming that the `c.getLocations()`, returns an array of `Locations`, then you can replace the second `for` loop (and then remove the corresponding closing curly bracket) with the following:

```
Location[] locations = c.getLocations();
Location l = locations[locations.length-1];
```

**UPDATE**: Since you commented that `c.getLocations()` returns an ArrayList, then you can use:

```
ArrayList<Location> locations = c.getLocations();
Location l = locations.get(locations.size()-1);
```

Another option would be to add a `getLastLocation()` method in the `Customer` class and then use:

```
Location l = c.getLastLocation();
```

instead of your second `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks! between the below use of getLast() and eliminating the for loop like you suggested it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

If `Location`s are stored as `LinkedList`, then just use `l.getLast()`. If it's an `ArrayList`, then use: `l.get(l.size() - 1)` .